When Refresh the page will go the homepage
Then problem i meet is when I login successfully and it will navigate to dashboard. However, When I refresh any page then it will navigate to Homepage. Therefore, May I know how should I modify the code to prevent this for occurring.
App.js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Admin from "./layouts/Admin.js";
import Parent from "./layouts/Parent.js";
import Auth from "./layouts/Auth.js";
import Teacher from "./layouts/Teacher";
import Landing from "./views/Landing.js";
import Profile from "./views/Profile.js";
import Index from "./views/Index.js";
import AuthGuard from "./views/auth/AuthGuard.js";
// import PersistLogin from "./layouts/PersistLogin.js";
import RequiredAuth from "./views/auth/RequiredAuth.js";
import { AuthContext } from "./config/context/AuthContext.js";
import ProtectedRoute from "./views/auth/ProtectedRoute.js";
import { db } from "./config/firebase.js";
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

function App() {
  const {currentUser, userRole} = useContext(AuthContext);

  const RequireAuth = ({ children }) => {
    console.log("currentUser : ", currentUser);
    if (currentUser !== null) {
      return children;
    } else {
      return <Navigate to="/auth/login" />;
    }
  };

  const RequireAdmin = ({ children }) => {
    if (currentUser && currentUser.role === "admin") {
      return children;
    } else {
      // Handle the case where currentUser is null or currentUser.role is not "admin"
      return <Navigate to="/" />;
    }
  };
  
  const RequireParent = ({ children }) => {
    if (currentUser && currentUser.role === "parent") {
      return children;
    } else {
      // Handle the case where currentUser is null or currentUser.role is not "parent"
      return <Navigate to="/" />;
    }
  };
  
  const RequireTeacher = ({ children }) => {
    console.log("currentUser : ", currentUser);
    if (currentUser && currentUser.role === "teacher") {
      return children;
    } else {
      // Handle the case where currentUser is null or currentUser.role is not "teacher"
      return <Navigate to="/" />;
    }
  };
  

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        {/* Routes with layouts */}
        <Route path="/admin/*" element={<RequireAdmin><Admin /></RequireAdmin>} />
        <Route path="/parent/*" element={<RequireParent><Parent /></RequireParent>} />
        <Route path="/teacher/*" element={<RequireTeacher><Teacher /></RequireTeacher>}/>
        
        <Route path="/auth/*" element={<AuthGuard><Auth /></AuthGuard>} />
        
        {/* Routes without layouts */}
        <Route path="/landing" element={<Landing />} />
        <Route path="/profile" element={<RequireAuth><Profile /></RequireAuth>} />
        <Route path="/" element={<Index />} />
        
        {/* Redirect all unmatched routes to the landing page */}
        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/landing" />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;


AuthContext.js
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { auth, db } from "../../config/firebase";
import {
  confirmPasswordReset,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  sendPasswordResetEmail,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  setPersistence,
  browserLocalPersistence,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const AuthContext = createContext();

const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  const [userRole, setUserRole] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initializeAuth = async () => {
      try {
        // Listen for authentication state changes
        onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
          setCurrentUser(user);
          setLoading(false);
          if (user) {
            try {
              const userRoleDoc = await getDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid));
              if (userRoleDoc.exists()) {
                const userData = userRoleDoc.data();
                user.role = userData.role;
                setUserRole(userData.role);
              }
            } catch (error) {
              console.error("Error fetching user role:", error);
            }
          } else {
            setUserRole(null);
          }
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error initializing authentication:", error);
      }
    };

    initializeAuth();
  }, []);

  function logIn(email, password) {
    // Set local persistence before attempting to sign in
    return setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence)
      .then(() => {
        // Sign in with email and password
        return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error setting persistence:", error);
        // If there's an error, return a rejected promise
        return Promise.reject(error);
      });
  }

  function forgotPassword(email) {
    return sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email, {
      url: "http://localhost:3000/login",
    });
  }

  function resetPassword(oobCode, newPassword) {
    return confirmPasswordReset(auth, oobCode, newPassword);
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        currentUser,
        userRole,
        logIn,
        forgotPassword,
        resetPassword,
      }}
    >
      {!loading && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { AuthContext, AuthContextProvider };



Login.js
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { db } from "../../config/firebase";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext } from "../../config/context/AuthContext";
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

export default function Login() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { logIn } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setError(false);
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const userCredential = await logIn(email, password);
      const user = userCredential.user;
      // Proceed with the rest of the login process
      if (user) {
        const userRoleDoc = await getDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid));
        if (userRoleDoc.exists()) {
          const userData = userRoleDoc.data();
          // Directly redirect to the dashboard based on the user's role
          redirectBasedOnRole(userData.role);
          return; // Exit the function to prevent further execution
        }
      }
      // If user role is not determined, default to "/"
      navigate("/");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Login error:", error);
      setError(true); // Set error state to display error message
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const redirectBasedOnRole = (role) => {
    switch (role) {
      case "admin":
        navigate("/admin/dashboard");
        break;
      case "parent":
        navigate("/parent/dashboard");
        break;
      case "teacher":
        navigate("/teacher/dashboard");
        break;
      default:
        navigate("/");
    }
  };

How to Persistence the user to avoid back to homepage while refresh the page
